# Centripetal Acceleration Of Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, centripetal-force

> Determine your centripetal acceleration due to rotation of the Earth.
>   The geographical latitude of Toronto is $\Phi=43^{\circ}$. Radius of
>   the Earth is $R=6.38\cdot 10^6$m.

**Textbook Answer:**

[image]

Why is $r$ in the equation not equal to the $R$ given which is the radius of the Earth?

And how was $v$ found? Plus where did $T$ come from??

Comment: There are 24 hours in one day (which is one rotation of the Earth).

Comment: If you were a few feet away from the North Geographic Pole, how big a circle would you be moving in?  The same as if you were on the equator?

Comment: @DJohnM  Ughhh, thanks. I get it now, but did you really have to answer a question with another question? -.- For anyone else with the same confusion, the radius of you rotating in Toronto is NOT the same as the raidus of you rotating in a location at the equator.

Comment: NoName, comments are not answers.  Here's a suggestion:  write that answer up with a hat tip to @DJohnM, post it and then accept it.  Your comment, as written, seems a bit churlish to me and I recommend that you delete it.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer so that the question is no longer answered in the comments.

---

The radius at which you're rotating around the Earth's axis is not the same for all places on Earth, and depends on the latitude ($\phi$) of the observer.

For example: one metre away from the (geographic) North Pole you would move in a circle of radius $1m$, whilst when close to the equator you would move in a circle of more than $6000m$

Thanks to @DJohnM for originally answering in the comments section.